# How to disable "split view"?

Tags: macos, split-view

Is it possible to bring back simple window maximize button as it was before and when holding option to use split view?

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you asking for. You want application windows to take up the whole screen? Not like full screen mode?

Comment: You can disable Split View (I found this out today, quite by accident). System Preferences > Mission Control > Uncheck `Displays have separate Spaces`.  As far as window maximizing, I don't know if it's possible to bring back the button, but you can double click the toolbar to maximize a window.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change that function of Full Screen button to, but there is simple workaround. Go to Keyboard Preference Pane > Shortcuts > App Shotcuts > + > All Applications, and Menu Title to **Zoom/Maximise**, choose a shortcut of your preference. Now you can use that shortcut to mimic the behaviour of "old" Maximise button.

[image: Adding a Zoom Shortcut]